# How to execute a "INSERT INTO" query to a remote database with linux command line?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linux, database, bash

I'm tryng to create a code in raspbian system to update a value in my database mySQL stored into my hosting server using a bash ".sh" scrypt.

this line won't to work but I don't know why...

```
mysql -h eliuslab.com -u user -pPassWord -D mydatabase -e "INSERT INTO 'home-IP' ('IP') VALUES ('192.168.1.2')"
```

And the output:

```
 'ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''home-IP' ('IP') VALUES ('192.168.1.2')' at line 1 '
```

this query works well in a GUI mySQL client, but what I want to do is to launch this action with my ".sh" bash scrypt.

Thank you so much :)

Comment: Any specific error you are getting ?

Comment: 'ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''home-IP' ('IP') VALUES ('192.168.1.2')' at line 1
'
192.168.1.2 is the value that I'm tryng to insert into the cell
home-IP is the table name and 'IP' is the column

Comment: Did you executed the command I have written in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got the solution. I ran your script in my mysql database and got the same error. It's not the fault of script but it's a parsing error.
The correct command  is

```
mysql -h eliuslab.com -u user -pPassWord -D mydatabase -e "INSERT INTO tablename (column) VALUES ('BLABLASTRING')"
```

Notice there is no need of using quotation marks around the table name and the column name. The quotation marks treat them as string constant  rather than a container.

Comment: Your code give me another error when I execute it. It's possible that it doesn't like the "-" into the tab name "home-IP"? If I don't put the ' ' give me an error with "-IP"

Comment: I can't because I should give you my sql password, can you help me anyway?

Comment: Replace the username and password  with dummy values and then paste the statement

Comment: mysql -h eliuslab.com -u user -pPassWord -D mydatabase -e "INSERT INTO home-IP (IP) VALUES ('192.168.1.2')" .

Run this Command

Comment: pi@raspberrypi ~ $ mysql -h eliuslab.com -u user -pPassword -D eliuslab-webservices -e "INSERT INTO 'home-IP' ('IP
') VALUES('192.168.1.2')"
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL serv
er version for the right syntax to use near ''home-IP' ('IP'
) VALUES('192.168.1.2')' at line 1

Comment: ok, is here:pi@raspberrypi ~ $ mysql -h eliuslab.com -u user -pPassword -D eliuslab-webservices -e "INSERT INTO home-IP(IP) VA
LUES ('192.168.1.2')"
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL serv
er version for the right syntax to use near '-IP(IP) VALUES
('192.168.1.2')' at line 1

Comment: mysql -h eliuslab.com -u user -pPassword -D eliuslab-webservices -e "INSERT INTO `\`home-IP\`` ('IP ') VALUES('192.168.1.2')"

Comment: pi@raspberrypi ~ $ mysql -h eliuslab.com -u user -pPassword -D eliuslab-webservices -e "INSERT INTO `home-IP`('IP'
) VALUES ('192.168.1.2')"
-bash: home-IP: command not found
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL serv
er version for the right syntax to use near '('IP') VALUES (
'192.168.1.2')' at line 1

Comment: Its pretty easy now. Remove the quotes around IP